# How do I change the default SMTP setting in Mail after an account has been created?

Tags: settings, pantheon-mail

First day using Elementary and I didn't change the default SMTP setting on a couple of accounts. Everything is grayed out in Mail, so I tried editing the .ini file in .local/share/pantheon-mail/ but that didn't change anything. It would be pretty useful if these settings could be changed.

Otherwise, a great distro!

Answer (score 1):

Editing server details is currently not possible in Geary accounts/edit, as [mentioned in the comment](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/12570/how-do-i-change-the-default-smtp-setting-in-mail-after-an-account-has-been-creat?newreg=4651a659a99943a6a3f0b92a464f37c2#comment15751_12573) from @globetrotterdk

It says in the help menu option:

> Editing existing accounts - From the Accounts dialog, select an account and click the pencil icon to change various settings. Please note that Geary cannot change server settings on an existing account. **If you need to change your IMAP or SMTP server, you will need to delete the account and re-add it**.

These Geary Account help docs are also available online [here](http://yorba.org/geary/help/accounts.html).

Answer (score 0):

Open Mail, go to the gear menu in the upper-right corner and select Accounts (or open Mail and press Ctrl + M). Select the account in question, and click the small edit icon in the lower-left corner (the pencil icon between the + and - icons). Double-clicking an account in the Accounts window will also open it for editing.Make your change and Save.

Comment: Both IMAP and SMTP settings are greyed out and impossible to edit in that view.

Answer (score 0):

It's grayed out for me too. I think the easiest would be to re-add these accounts...Still I'm not sure why there's no way of changing it inside Geary.
Did you open a bug report for that? If not you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its a little bit too late, but maybe somebody else will need it:

You can change the settings in

```
$HOME/.local/share/pantheon-mail/<your mail-account>/geary.ini
```

with a normal editor. The settings in patheon mail are not changed so I don't know if it is something which will work in the future.