# Can't update existing email account, also can't delete it to re-add it

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-mail

In the email program, I need to update the SMTP address for my single email account. According to [this answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/12570/how-do-i-change-the-default-smtp-setting-in-mail-after-an-account-has-been-creat) I have to delete my account and re-add it. But the option to delete the account is greyed out, so I can't delete it. I also can't add the same account again. Is there a way to delete the config files for this account?